# How to fix controller error in Ruby on Rails and get Paperclip up and running, still not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying for quite a while to get Paperclip up and running on my website and have followed the step-by-step process outlined on github multiple times and it still won't work. I really need to get this up and running as soon as possible. When I run the code through localhost, I get the message:

```
undefined local variable or method `survey' for #<SurveysController:0x007ff09e82aa50>
app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:18:in `survey_params'
app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Here is my code

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :new, :create, :survey_params, :owners, :seeker, :survey_params, :idcheck
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
    #if @survey.save
    #redirect_to root_path, notice: "Survey is created."
    #else
    #render 'new'
    #end
  end
  private

  def survey_params
    survey_params = params.require(survey).permit(:avatar)
  end

  private

  def owners
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
    @survey.user_id=current_user.id
    @survey.save
  end

  def seeker
    @survey = Survey.new
    @survey.save
  end

  private

  def idcheck
  end
end
```

---

```
<p>
                                        <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
                                    </p>
                                    <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>

            <!---</div>-->
            <div class="circle_wrapper roommates_both">
                <div class="dark_circle" ></div>
                <div class="light_circle" ></div>
                <div class="light_circle" ></div>
            </div>

            <div class="housing_only">
                <div class="submit_button">
                <input id="submit_room_only" class="nextbutton one pages submitbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" disabled/>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>

<% end %>
        <form action="FileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="upload">Upload your Profile Photo:</label><br />
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    <div class="roommates_both">
                <input id="next1" class="nextbutton one pages" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save and continue >"/>
            </div>
</form>
```

---

What can I do to finally get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Change `survey_params` to (missed colon):

```
def survey_params
  survey_params = params.require(:survey).permit(:avatar)
end
```

And you have 3 `private`, remove last 2 (not an error, but bad smell).

Comment: also remove the second survey_params from your before filter